# Create a domain without buying it?

Tags: dns, dns-servers

I am a beginner with domains understanding and DNS configurations.

I already install BIND DNS server on my local centos machine and configure a domain `example.com` and set the virtual-host for Apache and it works very well

Can i do the same on my dedicated production server and assign any non parked domain without buying it from name registrars  and it will propagated to outside DNS servers? Or what is the idea exactly ?

Comment: Really? Do you really think there's a loophole that big in how the Internet works and only now *you* just figured it out?

Comment: You will always have to purchase the domain name from a registrar. You cannot simply claim your own or take over any existing non-used (or even used) domain name for your own use. That would be anarchy. It is not that your server propagates out, it only answers requests. Nothing more. Any domain name has to be registered and the DNS zone records created to tell the Internet where the domain can be found including top-level DNS servers.

Comment: no i know that it does not work like that .. i want to know how it work only what i miss in my understanding

Comment: @closetnoc really thanks for your detailed answer. i got it

Comment: The only way I can possibly see you scoring a free domain name or even close to it is if you worked for a provider of domain names or you work with ICANN. Other than that, I think you'll need to fork out at least $10 a year depending on who you sign up with.

Comment: @Mike the price is another issue. `.tk` domain names are free, price-wise. You can find others, in gTLDs specially, for low prices such as $0.99 during promotions, even if it is often only the first year. Even if you are a registrar you are restricted to what domain names you can buy for "yourself".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't. It will not propagate until is't properly registered (domain purchased, and NS configured).

Comment: one last question .. now when i stop the dns service on my local CentOS machine and when i go to my windows machine it still answer to that domain but linux not !! prehabs that due to windows dns caching so how i can make linux do like that

Comment: Windows machine will stop resolving this domain after some time, when DNS cache expires. To manually override DNS resolving on Windows machine, you can edit file located in windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts, and place there IP and domain which should be resolved to it. On your Linux machine, you can edit /etc/hosts (in most distributions it is located there), and add there IP and domain name of your internal website. The line will start from IP, and then the domain name which should be resolved to it. Example: 123.123.123.1 whatever.com

Comment: forget etc/host and hosts file in linux im talking about DNS cache in the system itself .. can i make linux cache DNS like windows?

Comment: I think caching DNS is not very good idea. External websites might have their IPs changed, and then long living local DNS cache will be a problem.

Comment: so you mean that DNS caching in windows is a bad thing right? i dont know even how long DNS caching in windows till expires

Comment: I don't say it's bad, but it shouldn't be too long. It's better to read something that describes DNS TTL: http://superuser.com/questions/80744/how-often-does-the-dns-cache-clear

Comment: ok can i do the same in linux

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020027/dns-caching-in-linux. What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: *It will not propagate until is't properly registered* this is slightly wrong in the sense that you can totally register a domain name (provision it in registry database) without it to be published at all if you do not specific any nameserver to it. A given percent (maybe 2% or 5%) of domain names are registered but not published either for registrant, registrar, or registry reasons (like disputes).

Answer (score 3):

You can install and configure any server, production or development, with any kind of domain name you like, existing or not, in real or fictional TLD, without having to pay for anything.

**But** no traffic based on this name will reach it unless clients do some specific configuration to be able to find it.

Like changing the content of `/etc/hosts` on a Unix machine so that you force the resolution of `your-shiny-new-domain.example` to be on your server IP address. This is helpful during development: you see things exactly as they will be later even if the domain name does not exist yet.

Of course, as soon as you really register the domain name (and there you will of course not be able to register one already existing nor one not using a TLD in the IANA root), it should be published in the global DNS and everyone will be able to reach it without any kind of specific configuration.